# How to shift the (0,0) point in a graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a graph that I need for my physics report and graphs have to be very precise.

[image: graph1]

How do I change the x-axis so it looks like this:
[image: graph2]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ned to select the axis - vertical in this case and set, in the axis options, that the axis crosses at zero. Shown in the image below.

[image]